# How to get the user joined time in Chat room in XMPP

Tags: ios, xmpp

I am developing an application where i want to know the user joined (first joined) time in the chat room. so that i can show the chat history only from that time. Is it possible. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: What do you call join ? Join is define in Groupchat specification (XEP-0045: Multi-User chat) and means sending a presence to the room. So, just send a presence to the room to join it.

Comment: For eg. I am inviting a user to join the room. when a user join the room by accepting my invitation, he should not see the previous history of the room. Is this achievable?

Comment: Yes, normally as a default the last 10 or 20 messages exchanged in the room are displayed unless the user ask to specifically disable the last message retrieval. If you want more you need to use Message Archive Management protocol to query the archive of the MUC room.

Comment: Thanks  Mickaël. I will check Message Archive.

Answer (score 0):

- Configure the server to disable the Chat History.

`mod_muc:
    history_size: 0`

- Ask for message history when first join the room, starting from your TimeJoined.
  http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#enter-history

Comment: Chat room history should be displayed per user not per room.

Comment: Xmpp protocol only provides generic functionality, how to use it is up to you. E.g. The server won't save messages for each user, but save for the room.